# Parsing a log file as XML

Tags: java, xml, parsing, logging

I've got a code here that takes the input of a file, and displays only certain lines containing the words "LANTALK" to the console, and then it writes out those lines to an external files. What I need, is to be able to filter the information within the lines to display in a certain way.

Here is the full code:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

public class baseline 
{

   // Class level variables
   static Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in); 

   public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, 
   FileNotFoundException { // Start of main

   // Variables  
   String filename;

   // Connecting to the output file with a buffer
   PrintWriter outFile = new PrintWriter(
                          new BufferedWriter(
                           new FileWriter("chatOutput.log")));

   // Get the input file
   System.out.print("Please enter full name of the file: ");
   filename = sc.next();

   // Assign the name of the input file to a file object
   File log = new File(filename);
   String textLine = null; // Null
   String outLine = "";    // Null
   BufferedWriter bw = null;



  try
  {
  // assigns the input file to a filereader object
     BufferedReader infile = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(log));

      sc = new Scanner(log);
            while(sc.hasNext())
            {
                String line=sc.nextLine();
                if(line.contains("LANTALK"))
                    System.out.println(line);
            } // End of while


  try
   {
     // Read data from the input file
    while((textLine = infile.readLine()) != null)
     {
       // Print to output file
       outLine = textLine;
       sc = new Scanner (outLine);
             while(sc.hasNext())
          {
               String line=sc.nextLine();
               if(line.contains("LANTALK"))
                outFile.printf("%s\n",outLine);
          }// end of while 
      } // end of while
    } // end of try


    finally  // This gets executed even when an exception is thrown 
       {
     infile.close();
     outFile.close();
       } // End of finally
     } // End of try


   catch (FileNotFoundException nf) // Goes with first try
   {
    System.out.println("The file \""+log+"\" was not found"); 
   } // End of catch
   catch (IOException ioex) // Goes with second try
   {
    System.out.println("Error reading the file");
   } // End of catch

  } // end of main

 } // end of class
```

Here is sample line of the input file:

```
08:25:26.668 [D] [T:000FF4] [F:LANTALK2C] <CMD>LANMSG</CMD>
<MBXID>1124</MBXID><MBXTO>5760</MBXTO><SUBTEXT>LanTalk</SUBTEXT><MOBILEADDR>
</MOBILEADDR><LAP>0</LAP><SMS>0</SMS><MSGTEXT>but didn't give me the info I 
needed</MSGTEXT>
08:25:26.672 [+] [T:000FF4] [S:1:1:1124:5607:5] LANMSG [0/2 | 0]
```

And here is what I'm trying to get the output to look like:

```
8:25:00 AM [Steve Jobs] to [John Smith] but didn't give me the info I needed
```

Does anyone have any suggestions on the best way to do this? I'm thinking some sort of an XML parser, but the file being read in is a .log, and I'm unsure of how to convert it in this instance since it has already been read. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You need an hybrid approach: read from the buffered reader the line that has LANTALK then the store in an stringbuilder from the first < to the last >. After that jsoup can do the xml trick for you

**Edit**

download jsoup from here

https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.jsoup/jsoup/1.8.3

Then in your if block just play with String indexOf and lastIndexOf until you have read the xml inside the log lines (put that into an string builder)

Comment: Alright. Do you happen to have some sort of an example of what that might look like? And is jsoup like a java resource pack I need to download?